# How to optimize query when join on varchar column in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B

```
select 
    A.ID, B.Name
from 
    A 
inner join 
    B on A.Name = B.Name
```

How to optimize this query? `name` column is `varchar(8)`

Comment: Which **RDBMS** is this for? Oracle? DB2? Sqlite? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? MySQL? Something else entirely? Please add at least one relevant tag!

Comment: It depends on how the sql engine decides to compile a plan but indexes on `A.name` and `B.name` would likely help considerably.

Comment: @Icemanind, reduce time to run query, for example, it takes 1 minutes to run query, use some method to reduced to  around 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an index on both tables A and B

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp